# How can I "mark as fixed" in Google's new Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors

In the "old" Google Search Console (and Google Webmaster Tools) there was an option to Mark as fixed to clear errors once fixed.

[image: Mark as fixed]

This allowed us to keep the error list clean and only show errors that are still relevant.

In the "new" version of the Search Console, where is this option?

Comment: I'll bet they removed it.   I have a feeling that people didn't know how to use it.   I've seen so many people try to mark 404 errors fixed after removing links to the page and then being surprised when the error comes back in a month.

Comment: I agree with Stephen, however, they are still migrating functionality so maybe it could be included in the future.

Comment: In the new version you can "Validate fix" (under Index, Coverage, click on the issue, and the button appears near the top right of the page) but the error will always appear on that page, even after Google verifies it is fixed. This allows them to show the "trend" column so you can see how often errors come back. If this doesn't work as well for you as the old report, I would suggest submitting feedback as they're still working on the new version.

Comment: The "validate fix" is much more awesome - it does more than just making the list disappear in the UI ("mark as fixed" just hid the error, it didn't do anything else on the backend).

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, there is no "Mark as fixed" Option in the new Google Search Console.

However, when you identify errors, you can click on "Validate Fix" which will get the error into "Processing" State until they are cleared (Passed).

As mentioned in the above comments by Stephen, it is misunderstood by lot of users how the functionality works correctly. The "Validate Fix" works better and often takes a lot of time to get processed.

We can wait for Google to see whether they are willing to bring this feature back in the new Search Console.

Sample URL:

[image: Validate Fix]

Comment: Where do you see a "Validate Fix" option? I don't seem to have that.

Comment: @AndrewLott I have updated the answer with a picture to help you. For identified errors, when you select the specific screen, it will show "Validate Fixes" option, highlighted in the red box in the image.

Comment: @idk Any idea why the error pages still show error with old date but when you click into one they are all green because I have fixed them? My client thinks the issue is still present because of the overview report.

Comment: @Styledev GSC updates the reports lately as I have observed. For the the same issue persisted till 4 months until everything was cleared up. For now, you can tell the same and show the fixed when you click on it.